# AngularJS Routes: is there a way to skip loading a controller (load template only)?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My `/home` template doesn't have an associated controller (it's blank). Anyway to skip loading the controller and just load the view? I'm using AngularAMD to lazy load so it's an additional call just to get a blank controller file.

```
  app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/home', {
        templateUrl 'home/home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController' //is empty because page is just static text
      })
      .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'login/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm, found that you can leave `controller: ''` blank and it works. It was just throwing an error in my case because I forgot to remove the `ng-controller="HomeController"` tag from the template/view. Once I removed that, the error was no longer being thrown (in console).